# Building an own socket API to send UDP packets over LoRaWAN

Tags: c, sockets, udp, lorawan

I'm building a LoRa network where the server and the end-device need to communicate using a protocol which normally transmits data via UDP. Due to the fact that these two protocols act totally different I need to find a way to combine those two.

One solution I found is to create my own socket API which provides send, receive, bind, ... functions. But here I'm actually struggling.

In which scope do I need to write my socket? Is it enough to just edit the functions and rely on the other given parameters such as the address families? Or must I define my own AF and if so where/how is this achieved.

I'm looking forward to your answers / ideas.

Answer (score 0):

According to the LoRaWAN specification and my limited experience, LoRaWAN is not suitable for such situation. If you still wanna use UDP packets over LoRaWAN, here are some tips for your question.

1. > In which scope do I need to write my socket?

You may use **sendUnconfirm** function since this function does not need ACK from gateway. And **port** in LoRaWAN could play the role of bind in UDP socket.

2. > Is it enough to just edit the functions and rely on the other given
   >   parameters such as the address families?

LoRaWAN server has its own features and structure. Usually, a LoRaWAN server is consist of packet_forwarder, LoRaWAN server and LoRaWAN application server. You may use these features to build you own **application** on LoRaWAN applicaiton server. It could save your a lot of time.

It is highly recommended to read LoRaWAN specification [(Get it here)](https://www.lora-alliance.org/lorawan-for-developers) and [TTN LoRaWAN wiki](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/wiki/LoRaWAN/Home) to help you get a better understanding in LoRaWAN.